# jQuery - Use .animate on .css

Tags: jquery, css, colors, jquery-animate

I wrote this script, which change colors of some elements when 'a' is hovered

```
$( "p > a" ).mouseover(function() {
  $('h3 a, .date, .post.text, p').css( "color", "#ddd" );
});
$( "a" ).mouseleave(function() {
  $('h3 a, .date, .post.text, p').css( "color", "#585858" );
});
```

This works fine but I'd like it to fade between these two states. I tried to implement .animate but it doesn't work. I'm still a learner of jQuery so I might be missing some point.

The idea is to highlight hovered element (a) by dimming colors of text around. There's maybe a better way to do this than changing colors in css too.

Thank you

Comment: can do this with css3 by toggling class that contains transitions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base jQuery version of `animate` can't animate colors, just things with straight numeric values. From the documentation:

> **Animation Properties and Values**

All animated properties should be animated to a *single numeric value*, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, `width`, `height`, or `left` can be animated but `background-color` cannot be, unless the [`jQuery.Color()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units `em` and `%` can be specified where applicable.

There are a few plugins for it (such as the one linked above), and [the functionality is included in jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/animate/).

Comment: Thanks, I will check jQuery UI. Is there maybe a work around ? Maybe animate opacity of selected elements, but how can I tell jQuery to apply the new opacity to everything except the element being hovered?

Comment: @Xavier: Using a plugin would be the workaround. :-) Re your opacity question, you could use `$("some selector").not(this).animate(...)`, to leave the element being hovered (`this` within either of the event handlers in your question) out of the set being animated.

Comment: Alright, I think I have enough leads here to solve my problem, thanks for your great help!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use jquery for it but I use css the most of the time.
Here's a little used example applying `transition` from css.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d7tc/)

---

Hope you like it for your css file. (: